# How to handle Redis Connection in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis, ioredis

How can I handle the Redis connection error gracefully in nodejs? I would like to return data from database not only when the redis cache is missed but even when the redis server is not connected. The main use case is that I would like to switch on the Redis server only during the peak hours and switch off during off-peak hours. Even with redis server off, I would like my nodejs application running without exiting.

I am trying to setup a file with redis connection so that other modules can import and can use the connections. Following codes are using ioredis (4.19.4) but I also tried with node-redis (3.0.2) and similar result too.

```
#redis_connection.js
const redis = require("ioredis");

const client = new redis.createClient("redisurl", {
  connectTimeout: 2000,
  lazyConnect: true,
  maxRetriesPerRequest: 2,
  reconnectOnError: function(err) {
    return false
  },
  retryStrategy: function(times) {
    return null
  }
});

client
.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log('Redis error >', e)
});

module.exports = {
  client,
}
```

Then, in my other modules, I am importing as following and use in some of my express functions.

```
import { client } from './redis_connection.js';

const getRealData = async () => {
  let article_data = null;
  try {
    client.get("key", function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("ERR IN TRY");
        console.error(err)
      } else {
        article_data = data;
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("CATCH");
    console.log(error);
  }

  if (article_data) {
    return article_data
  } else {
    // get the data from database
    return data_from_database
  }
}
```

When I run my application with invalid redis URL, the `Redis error >` is shown. Hence, the listener is working. Then, `ERR IN TRY` is shown. So far so good.

Then, the nodejs application exit with following error:

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Redis connection to connection_url:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.x.x:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at RedisClient.on_error (/Users/aungmt/project/node_modules/redis/index.js:341:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/aungmt/project/node_modules/redis/index.js:222:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xx.xx.x.x',
  port: 6379
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**Update**

Since I was trying with both ioredis and node-redis, look like it is conflicting. I uninstalled both and installed only ioredis. Now the nodejs application won't exit. However, ioredis keeps trying to reconnect as following although I tried with configs AND tried calling `disconnect()` manually. Thanks.

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/aungmt/project/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/index.js:308:37)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:416:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:479:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/aungmt/project/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/index.js:308:37)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:416:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:479:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

Comment: It feels you are using an older version of ioredis. I quick tested it here and was not able to reproduce. Try to update it to a newer.

Comment: I am using the latest version ioredis 4.19.4 but i have redis (node redis) 3.0.2 too. Could it be because of it?

Comment: Look like ioredis and node redis were conflicting. I uninstalled both and now installed only ioredis and it is partially working. now node application won't crash but ioredis keep trying to reconnect..

Comment: Default behavior is to retry. Take a look at their documentation it should help you configure the client the way you want. https://github.com/luin/ioredis#auto-reconnect

Comment: I managed to get this working. Look like retry behaviour is different between host + port way of connecting and redisurl connecting.